# Декораторы, хуки или манкипатчинг в makefile

Tags: makefile

Есть большущий тулчейн (`openwrt`). Хочу вставить обработчики перед и после `packages/install`.

Как это лучше реализовать не трогая код в дереве гит опенврт?

Например можно перезаписать эту функцию
 https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/include/rootfs.mk#L49 , если  я просто переопределю её в другом файле - она будет вызвана из него?

Comment: «в другом» — это в каком?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin «в другом» - например в файл виртуального пакета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

директива `define` — это [просто «другой путь» для определения переменной](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html).

одна и та же переменная может переопределяться сколько угодно раз. актуальным будет **последнее** определение.

директива `include` [указывает программе *make* отложить дальнейшее чтение текущего файла и начать чтение указанного в директиве, после чего продолжить чтение текущего](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).

---

таким образом, при наличии цепочки связанных директивами `include` файлов, сколько бы [пере]определений переменной ни встретилось в этих файлах, гарантированно задать ей **своё** значение можно, например, добавив это определение ниже последней директивы `include` в самый первый файл из цепочки.